# Setting width to an element

Tags: css, html

I have a problem and I have no idea how to fix it.

So here it is:

I am trying to display a number of text chunks one above the other. All of them are contained in nice text blocks. To implement the blocks I am using divs with a set width. It was all nice and fancy until I have tested my code in FF - and guess what? My little precious divs stretch or squeeze to envelop the content. What do I do to make them display properly in FF? Chrome and IE work perfectly well.

Here's the code I am using for the text blocks:

css:

```
#block {
    border: 2px dashed grey;
    background-color:  #D3D3D3;
    width: 338 px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.left {
float:right;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="block" class="left">
    <p>A long line of text that should take more than one line to display, 
       because I like long sentences - it is easy to get lost in them and 
       forget what you were writing about.</p>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div id="block" class="left">
    <p>two words</p>
</div>
```

Thank you very much. Like real much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rince, your issue is very simple. When you put the space in between `338` and `px` in your `width:`, FireFox cannot interpret it as a unit and so it ignores that line. Just remove the space and it works quite dandily

Answer (score 2):

Use the `max-width:` attribute for your div's.

```
width: 338px;
max-width: 338px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `max-width` and `min-width` tags as well as the `width` tag?  This may force it to only show at that particular size in FireFox as well as Chrome and Internet Explorer

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the solution but you need to be careful so you have only *1* item on a page with the same ID. I see that you're setting the ID to all of these as block. You should probably want to set that as the class instead and then just give the class of the DIVs as two classes, for example:

css:

```
.block {
       border: 2px dashed grey;
       background-color:  #D3D3D3;
       width: 338px;
       margin-top: 10px;
   }

.left {
      float:right;
      margin-right: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="block left">
    <p>A long line of text that should take more than one line to display, 
       because I like long sentences - it is easy to get lost in them and 
       forget what you were writing about.</p>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div class="block left">
    <p>two words</p>
</div>
```

Also, make sure you're consistent when you set the "px" property in CSS. Make sure there aren't any spaces between it and the numbers (like you have in the block class's width property)